# Want to convert array to duplicate key object in Node js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, object

I Want to convert the array to duplicate key object in Nodejs. following is my array data,

```
{
    "name" : "ashesh",
    "address_data" : [
        {
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "pincode": "400097"
        },
        {
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "pincode": "1000001"
        }
    ]
}
```

want to convert the array to the following object

```
{
    "name" : "ashesh",
    "address_data" : {
        "address" : {
            "city" : "Mumbai",
            "pincode": "400097"
        },
        "address" : {
            "city" : "Delhi",
            "pincode": "1000001"
        }
    }
}
```

How can I achieve this structure in node js or in javascript. Please help me on this. I know this is not a valid JSON but want to convert above structure. I am stuck to achieve this structure.

Comment: Your second code block isn't valid Javascript.  There is no such thing as duplicate keys in Javascript.  Usually, one would use an array to represent multiple values for the same property.

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: Objects can only have 1 value per key. If you set the same key to multiple values, it will usually just keep the last one (or else throw an error).

Comment: @ashesh How do you plan to access/iterate through the data if you have duplicate keys in object. Think over it and you'd understand why Object doesn't have duplicate keys

Comment: @binariedMe I know one object don't have duplicate key but want to achieve this, bcoz some one want this type of data in request

Comment: @jfriend00 yes, I know it's not valid JSON, but some system wants data in this format. So i want to achieve it.

Comment: No one can want such data structure. Again as I said, iteration/access of data over object is through keys and if there are duplicate keys, how would you make sure which data to return. Think over it bro. What you want is an array with the keys address as in 

address_data : [ address1, address2, address3]

Comment: And if you still want such a data structure only way you can do is send a string value in this type of structure. There's no other way around.

Comment: @binariedMe yes, same things I told them but they want same data structure. So what I have to do?

Comment: @binariedMe you have any example for this.

Comment: Ask them how they want to use this data. Despite, you can still send a string and as you know http carries text, you should be good to go. Let them worry about the data structure. You just make a string and send it\

Comment: they want in JSON object, that's why I'm stocked here.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152003/discussion-between-binariedme-and-ashesh-khatri).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If some third party still wants duplicate keys, instead create a string in the format of JSON object and send them.
Remember this string won't be compliant to JSON and you won't be able to parse it.

```
var a = { 
"name" : "ashesh", 
"address_data" : [ 
{ 
"city" : "Mumbai", 
"pincode": "400097" 
}, 
{ 
"city" : "Delhi", 
"pincode": "1000001" 
} 
] 
} 

var b = `{"name": "${a.name}", "address_data": {`; 

a.address_data.forEach((x) => b = b + `"address": ${JSON.stringify(x)}`); 
b = b + "}}"; 
b = b.replace(/\}"address"/g, `},"address"`);
res.send(b);
```